# Может ли орфографическое правило повлиять на речевой слух?

Tags: орфография, знак

Речь идет о написании мягкого знака в середине слова. Характер этого правила - эмпирически-статистический, и на запись слова по слуху оно ориентировано в последнюю очередь. Примерная статистика такова (чисто приблизительно): 35% слов – Ь после Л ПИШЕТСЯ по слуху; 50% слов – Ь после Д/Т, З/С, Н  НЕ ПИШЕТСЯ вопреки слуху; 15 % - Ь выбирается по механическому правилу, и ещё ряд исключений.
Правилом никто не пользуется, мягкий знак народ пишет по интуиции и относится к нему с недоверием, объяснить обычно никто и ничего не может.

Изменить же ситуацию можно очень просто: надо только объяснить отсутствие Ь после Д/Т, З/С, Н – тогда проверка будет не нужна, всё будет писаться по слуху, и никаких исключений, и полное понимание ситуации со стороны пользователей.

А как вы выбираете мягкий знак?

Answer (score 2):

ТЕОРИЯ

1. Мягкий звук  Л всегда на письме обозначается мягким знаком, в том числе перед шипящими (только собственная мягкость): апельсин, льстить, сельдь, мельчайший.
   (Сонорные Р и М также всегда имеют собственную мягкость: зорька, восемьдесят).
2. В сочетаниях пяти зубных согласных Д/Т, З/С и Н мягкий знак не пишется (несобственная мягкость первого звука): бантик, мостик, песня  и др.
3. Если второй согласный твердый, то мягкость первого всегда собственная: тоньше, сентябрьский, июньский, день-деньской.
4. Особые случаи:
    А) В сочетаниях НС/НЗ наметилась тенденция к отсутствию ассимиляции Н перед С: пенсия – пансионат, но правила на это пока не отреагировали, Ь не пишется.
   Б) Мягкий знак может быть грамматическим: бросьте, встаньте.
5. Для шипящих: А) в сочетаниях НЧ, НЩ - несобственная мягкость Н, Ь не пишем: кончик, тончайший, каменщик; Б) в сочетаниях ЧК, ЧН, ЩН, ЧТ не обозначается мягкость всегда мягких Ч, Щ: ночной, мощный, почти.

НА ПРАКТИКЕ:

Горький – оба согласных незубные, пишем Ь.

Судьба, возьми, тесьма – один согласный незубный, пишем Ь

Вести, вентиль, здесь – оба согласных зубные, не пишем Ь

Во всех случаях легко и просто можно выбрать мягкий знак и объяснить его выбор. Присылайте слова, которые это правило не объясняет.

Answer (score 1):

Если честно, я просто помню, в каких словах должен быть мягкий, а в каких твердый знак. В некоторых словах твердый уж никак по слуху не поставишь - после Л, например. Ну и в совсем сложных случаях лезу в словарь или ищу в интернете. То есть, для меня это правило из раздела "это надо запомнить".)))
Было бы интересно услышать мнение других форумчан.

Comment: Грузинский анекдот.
Тарелька, вилька пишется без мягкого знака, 
а кон, сол и фасол с мягким. Дети - это невозможно 
понять, это нужно просто запомнить!

Вспомнилось....

Comment: Этот же анекдот, но немного по-другому:
- Дети, запомните, а лучше запишите:тарелька, вилька пишется без мягкого знака, а кон, сол и фасол с мягким.

Answer (score 0):

Этот параграф у Розенталя:
 § 35 п. 10

§ 30. Для обозначения мягкости парного согласного перед согласными буква ь пишется в следующих случаях.

1. После буквы л перед любым согласным, кроме л, напр.: пальба, львиный, фольга, льдина, скользить, несколько, ни бельмеса, спальня, внимательно, скальпель, вальс, пальтишко, льстить, ап- рельский, альфа, ольха, зеркальце, мальчик, больше, польщённый.

[Ссылка на источник](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=25#pp25)